# Out of memory - default matlab database and code

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I'm learning nn toolbox with matlab examples and i've got all time error

> Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your
>   options. Error in test2 (line 10) xTest = zeros(inputSize,numel(xTestImages));

Here is my simply code

```
% Get the number of pixels in each image
imageWidth = 28;
imageHeight = 28;
inputSize = imageWidth*imageHeight;

% Load the test images
[xTestImages, outputs] = digittest_dataset;

% Turn the test images into vectors and put them in a matrix
xTest = zeros(inputSize,numel(xTestImages));
for i = 1:numel(xTestImages)
    xTest(:,i) = xTestImages{i}(:);
end
```

code is written according to 
[mathwork example](http://www.mathworks.com/examples/neural-network/mw/nnet_product-AutoencoderDigitsExample-training-a-deep-neural-network-for-digit-classification?s_tid=srchtitle) (but im trying to do my own custom network). I reinstall matlab, make maximum java RAM storage, clean some disk space and delate rest of neural network. Still not working. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the value of numel(xTestImages)?

Comment: @tim it's from digittest_dataset - default matlab database. xTestImages is cell 1x5000

Comment: That means, `xTest = zeros(inputSize,numel(xTestImages));` would yield a matrix of size 28^2*5000= 3,920e6 elements. Every element has a double precision (8byte), hence the matrix should only consume around 30mb... What does the output of the command `memory` show?

Comment: Maximum possible array:     29 MB (3.054e+07 bytes) * Memory available for all arrays:    467 MB (4.893e+08 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    624 MB (6.547e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3067 MB (3.216e+09 bytes) . So it seems ok. Good point with this 30mb :) Problem must be in another place

Comment: Ill post an answer, maybe it is of any help for you, if so, please accept :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written above, the line:

```
xTest = zeros(inputSize,numel(xTestImages)); # xTestImages is 1x5000
```

would yield a matrix of size `28^2*5000= 3,920e6` elements. Every element has a double precision (8byte), hence the matrix would consume around 30mb...

You stated, that the command `memory` shows the following:

```
Maximum possible array: 29 MB (3.054e+07 bytes) 
* Memory available for all arrays: 467 MB (4.893e+08 bytes) 
** Memory used by MATLAB: 624 MB (6.547e+08 bytes) 
Physical Memory (RAM): 3067 MB (3.216e+09 bytes)
```

So the first line shows the limitation for ONE single array.

So a few things to consider:

- I guess `clear all` or quitting some other running applications does not improve the situation!?
- Do you use a 64 or 32bit OS? And/or MATLAB 32/64 bit?
- Did you try to change the Java Heap Settings? https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/java-heap-memory-preferences.html

I know this won't fix the problem, but maybe it will help you to keep on working in the meanwhile: You could create the matrix with single precision which should work for your testcase. Simply pass `single` as second option while creating the matrix.

Comment: I quit all aplication. Value of Java heap size for max amount. I just start use 1000 samples and its work. But when i try use it with neural network i still got problems with run out of memory (even on 10 samples). Matlab2015SP1 32bit at Windows 7 32bit. I afraid maybe it's just too low for this calculates :( Anyway for this issue your answer is good. If i don't solve problem with my neural network i create new topic. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Out of memory was created by Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm - it's create huge Jacobian matrix for calculations when data is big.